# Cloudera manager - hadoop installation failure

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Try install Cloudera Manager. 
Failed on step auto install in the hadoop hosts.

```
Error:
Installing JDK package...
BEGIN yum info jdk 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror 
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile 
* base: archive.cs.uu.nl 
* extras: archive.cs.uu.nl 
* updates: mirror.fraunhofer.de 
http://archive.cloudera.com/redhat/cdh/3/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')> 
Trying other mirror. 
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: cloudera-cdh3. Please verify its path and try again 
END (1) 
remote package jdk is not available, giving up


From OS command 
yum info jdk 
complete success.

In the OS set proxy (export http_proxy=....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera SCM fails because it is not able to use yum to download and install JDK.

So far I have seen it always tries to do that.

You can update yum repository on the machines yourself, depending on what version of Linux you are using.

Here is example using RHEL / OEL 5:

```
# This adds Oracle Yum repo
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://public-yum.oracle.com/public-yum-el5.repo

# This adds Fedora EPEL yum repo
yum remove epel-release-5-4
rpm -Uvh http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora-epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

See if you can install JDK manually.

[Edit:]

Check if you are able to do the following with out issues:

```
python
>>> import urllib
>>> x = urllib.urlopen('http://archive.cloudera.com/redhat/cdh/3/repodata/repomd.xml')
>>> x.getcode()
200
>>> print x.readlines()
```

Comment: Main problem - this error [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')>. I can install from linux console, but i couldn't install from web interface cloudera

Comment: @Kukuruka: See edited answer. I see that it is unable to fetch the package info using yum repository. You can debug it exactly as SCm does in it's code. It should throw the same error else try removing the Cloudera repository and adding it again manually